# Work and energy question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

> - An athlete picks up a $20.0\,\mathrm{kg}$ sandbag from the ground and throws t straight up in the air. It leaves her hands $1.50\,\mathrm{m}$ above the ground and reaches a height of $7.00\,\mathrm{m}$
>
> How much work did the athlete do?

So i tried this problem by myself and got the wrong answer.

First, i found the final speed which was $v_f^2 = 2gh = 10.4\,\mathrm{m/s}$

Then, in order to find work i used $W = K_f - K_i$

$W = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = 1081.6\,\mathrm{J}$

However, the textbook suggests different approach for this problem.

It says that for $W = U_f + K_f = mgh +0 = 1.37\,\mathrm{kJ}$

I'm really confused about this approach, what is $U_f$ and why the formula that I used for Work did not work?

Comment: The work done by the athlete includes lifting the bag from the ground to the release point of 1.5m.  Did you include that in your calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work that the athlete does is in throwing the sandbag up to a height of 7.00m.

You have calculated the final speed of the sandbag as it reaches the ground again, however once the sandbag reaches the height of 7m, it has no kinetic energy any more and is at rest (with $v_f = 0$).

Now, *gravity* takes over: the kinetic energy has been completely converted to potential energy $U_f$ when the sandbag reaches $h = 7m$.

In this case, we can say that $K_f - K_i = \frac12 mv_i^2 - 0 = mgh = U_f$ and therefore the work done is $W = U_f + K_f = mgh + 0$

Comment: Now it makes sense ! I read about the potential energy and now i totally get it ! Thank you!